# Check if multiple keys exists in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to validate the request object to check if specific keys exist in the object or not. I've tried `lodash`'s `has()` function, but it seems that `_.has()` checks nested JSON. JavaScript's `.hasOwnProperty()` takes one key at a time. Is it possible to check an array of keys within a plain JSON object?

The object I am trying to check is:

```
{
    "name": "admin@test.org",
    "oldPassword": "1234",
    "newPassword": "12345"
}
```

Comment: Why not check like `obj.name && obj.oldPassword && obj.newPassword` ? If you want to check for a fixed structure, you need to have some sort of types like Typscript provides for example.

Comment: @DavidJoos It will be a bit tedious in case the object gets multiple keys.

Comment: sure, but especially in this case i wouldn't hesitate to use it like this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply use Object.keys and every

```js
const neededKeys = ['oldPassword', 'name', 'newPassword'];

const obj = {
    "name": "admin@test.org",
    "oldPassword": "1234",
    "newPassword": "12345"
}

console.log(neededKeys.every(key => Object.keys(obj).includes(key)));
```

Comment: would `Object.keys(obj).every(key => neededKeys.includes(key));` be more efficient? I imagine `Object.keys` would require an iteration over the object each time. So if you're only doing it once, instead of n times would it be better this way?

Comment: Yes, but that would fail if there's an additional key in the object (which might be allowed)... @NickParsons. However, it would surely be better to create a variable holding `Object.keys(obj)`s value and check with that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` operator to check if keys exist in object or not. It is quite faster than `Object.keys` as its complexity is O(1) as compared to `Object.keys` with complexity of O(n)

Example:

```
const neededKeys = ['oldPassword', 'name', 'newPassword'];

const obj = {
    "name": "admin@test.org",
    "oldPassword": "1234",
    "newPassword": "12345"
}

console.log(neededKeys.every(key => key in obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.includes` method of an array and `Object.keys` will give you an array of all the keys. You can compare this with an array of keys from which you want to check using a loop

```js
var a = {
  "name": "admin@test.org",
  "oldPassword": "1234",
  "newPassword": "12345"
};
var key = ["name", "oldPassword", "newPassword"];
Object.keys(a).forEach(e => key.includes(e) ? console.log(e + " found") : console.log(e + " not found"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myobj =  {
    "name": "admin@test.org",
    "oldPassword": "1234",
    "newPassword": "12345"
}
```

```
Print (myobj.keys() >= {"name","oldPassword","newPassword"})
```

-- this will return True

```
Print (myobj.keys() >= {"name1","id","firstname"})
```

-- this will return false